# iOS - Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' stuck in Github Actions

Tags: ios, swift, github-actions

I'm setting up a CI pipeline for an iOS application using GitHub Actions.

When executing a build command:

```
  xcodebuild \
  -workspace xxx.xcworkspace \
  -scheme SecureImage \
  clean build | xcpretty
```

It gets stuck on `Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'` until it times out based on the 2 hour time out I've set.

```
▸ Compiling Main.storyboard
▸ Compiling Albums.storyboard
▸ Processing Info.plist
▸ Running script '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

After a lot of googling, I suspect the only thing that could be, is something to do with the keychain but I can't see what.
This is my script for adding the certificates after decrypting them:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

cp ./.github/secrets/Provisioning.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/Provisioning.mobileprovision


security create-keychain -p "" ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security import ./.github/secrets/Certificates.p12 -t agg -k ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain -P "" -A

security list-keychains -s ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security default-keychain -s ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
security unlock-keychain -p "" ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain

security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k "" ~/Library/Keychains/build.keychain
```

I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to install pods before building

```
- name: Install CocoaPod Dependencies
      run: pod install
```